# Node.js: How to attach to a running process and to debug the server with a console?

Tags: node.js, console

I use 'forever' to run my application. I want to attach to the running environment to inspect my application. So what can I do?

Comment: = =  not really. I just know about three commands: 1.forever start my_script.js;  2.forever list// list all running node processes; 3.forever stop my_pid //you can find the pid by running 'forever list';  And enough for me -,- . If necessary, I will go to Google for help, that's my style  ^ ^

Answer (score 66, accepted):

From http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html:

> #### Advanced Usage
>
> The V8 debugger can be enabled and accessed either by starting Node with the --debug command-line flag or by signaling an
> existing Node process with SIGUSR1.

Find the PID of your `node` process and then sending `SIGUSR1` should do the trick:

```
kill -s SIGUSR1 nodejs-pid
```

Then run `node-inspector` and browse to the URL it indicates. More in [this tutorial](http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/34843655876/debugging-with-node-inspector).

Comment: I tried : $ node debug my_script.js, But the script must run by steps manually. What I need is to run it as normal and attach it to the already running process and test it with a interactive console. But really appreciate your help   ^ ^

Comment: @Croplio: what Bill said works. See [this tutorial](http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/34843655876/debugging-with-node-inspector).

Comment: @Croplio, It is `node --debug my_script.js`, with `--debug`, not `debug` (note the two hyphens)

Comment: This answer is outdated, node-inspector is no longer needed

Comment: Is it also possible to disable debugging with a signal?

Comment: is this still true, v10+

Comment: Link to the tutorial - https://web.archive.org/web/20160421064215/http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/34843655876/debugging-with-node-inspector

Answer (score 57):

Starting from **Node 6.3**, node has a built-in debugger that can be triggered (even in a production app) by doing:

```
kill -USR1 <node-pid>
```

The node process will spit out something like this:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/f3f6f226-7dbc-4009-95fa-d516ba132fbd
For help see https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

- If you can access the server from a browser, you can use [`chrome://inspect`](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27) on `http://host.domain:9229`.
- If you cannot connect via a browser (e.g. the server is in a firewalled production cluster), you can activate a REPL to inspect over the command line:

  ```
  node inspect -p <node-pid>
  ```
- If you can't access the server from a browser, but you can SSH into that server, then setup SSH port forwarding (`ssh -nNTL 9229:localhost:9229 <username>@<your_host> -i <keyfile>.pem`) and you'll find your script under `chrome://inspect` after a few seconds.

Prior to this version, [`node-inspector`](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) was a separate tool for debugging Node processes. However, as documented on its own page, it is mostly deprecated as the now-bundled debugger is actively maintained and provides more advanced features. For more information on this change, see [this thread](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/8464).

Comment: Looks promising, but I tried this on Node v10.15.2 (Debian), it seemingly did nothing and I just got a new prompt

Answer (score 10):

## Windows users

### */edit 2022*

This is what I use currently, configured in ***settings.json***. This will prompt you to select a process and it will send the debug signal to it automatically. Read more below to understand what's happening.

[image]

```
  "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Attach to Process (Pick)",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "attach",
        "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
        "port": 9229,
      }
    ]
  },
```

---

### Previously

If you are on Windows that doesn't support POSIX signals, you can use this workaround from **another** `cmd`.

```
node -e "process._debugProcess(PID)"
```

---

For a **detailed guide**, or to set up debugging in VSCode, follow these simple steps:

1. In VSCode, open `launch.json` configuration or create new by clicking on the wheel
   <sup>*(this is the debug view <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>)*</sup>

[image]

2. The node will listen on port 9229 [by default](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enable-inspector), so add this configuration:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "name": "Attach to 9229",
  "port": 9229
},
```

3. Open Task Manager and locate the PID of your node process
   I could identify my by the `"build"` folder where the `index.js` is.
   [image]
4. open **another** `cmd` or `git-bash` and run this command,
   where `21392` is the PID of your process.

```
node -e "process._debugProcess(21392)"
```

5. you should see this[image: Debugger listening on ws:9229]
6. Start debugging from VSCode *Attach to 9229*
   [image]

Everything should be ready now.

Comment: PS: This is how to run VSCode in WSL mode and connect to a linux process. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Answer (score 7):

For me, running node version 6.9.10 I had to:

`kill -USR1 <node-pid>`

then

`node debug -p <node-pid>`

the `node inspect -p <node-pid>` command failed for this version of node.

Answer (score 5):

You can add a [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) to your app. For example, if you add a REPL to listen on localhost port 5001, you start your app as usual and login with telnet: `telnet localhost 5001`. That will take you to a prompt where you can interact with your app directly.

Alternatively, if you need to your app to "pause" when it reaches a certain state, you need to add "debugger;" lines to areas of your code where you want those breakpoints, then start the app in [debug](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) mode.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even it's an old yet answered question, there is an easier way, which is passing parameters to node:

```
forever start -c 'node --debug-brk' main.js
```

If you don't want to wait for debugger to be attached, replace `--debug-brk` by `--debug`

Answer (score 0):

**To inspect nodejs and debug it, use this command**

`forever -w -c 'node --inspect=IP:PORT' file.js`

- **-c** if for a **custom command**
- use **-w to reload** if the file is **re-save**
- You can **pass ip and port** for **external inspect**
- port custom is **9229**