# Node.js: inspect what's left in the event loop that's preventing the script from exiting naturally

Tags: node.js

Node.js script won't exit if there's callbacks left in the main event loop. While one could forcefully terminate the script by calling `process.exit()` or throwing exceptions, it is recommended to let the script terminate "naturally", by always doing proper cleanup. However, this sometimes can be difficult as bugs in the code may prevent proper cleanup, e.g., I may forget to remove an IntervalObject when no longer needed, etc., which eventually prevents the program from terminating.

Therefore, is there a way to debug a non-terminating script to find out what's remaining registered in the event loop? In other words, is there a way in Node.js to debug what's preventing the program from exiting?

Comment: Maybe this: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052548/node-js-how-to-attach-to-a-running-process-and-to-debug-the-server-with-a-conso

 can be useful to you?

Comment: @StefanoF No, I believe that's irrelevant. Thanks for commenting anyways.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can call `process._getActiveRequests()` to get a list of active I/O requests and `process._getActiveHandles()` to get a list of open handles/file descriptors.

Comment: I would suggest to use an NPM module like [wtfnode](https://github.com/myndzi/wtfnode), [why-is-node-running](https://github.com/mafintosh/why-is-node-running) or [active-handles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/active-handles) to determine which piece of code is causing the issue.

Comment: But exercise due diligence: check the activity for each over on the npm registry: [wtfnode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode), [why-is-node-running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running), and [active-handles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/active-handles). Of the three, only "why is node running" appears to still make sense in 2023.

Answer (score 34):

The [`wtfnode`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wtfnode) package utilizes the tools mentioned by @mscdex but presents in a more developer-friendly way. I highly recommend this for tracking down these annoyances.

```
const wtf = require('wtfnode');

// ...

wtf.dump();
```

Comment: This was fantastically easy and helpful!

Answer (score 3):

Node.js, starting from version 8, provides a handy module to retrieve this kind of information.

[async_hooks](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/async_hooks.html): an API to register callbacks tracking the lifetime of asynchronous resources created inside a Node.js application.