# what prevents node.js to exit process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there any way to debug or determine what prevents node.js script to exit?
All my code run is finished, I removed all event listeners, but process is still active.

Comment: You'll need to include some code to reproduce the issue, or at least a thorough description of what you're doing that may cause the process to stick around.

Comment: exit when? can you give more info and/or code examples. do you mean error out? do you have logs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js: inspect what's left in the event loop that's preventing the script from exiting naturally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057328/node-js-inspect-whats-left-in-the-event-loop-thats-preventing-the-script-from)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `process.exit(<code>)` to leave the program and check what they call "event loop" too

source : http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

and : http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html