# How can I get all timers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I create different timer with `setTimeout()` function in different class. I want to know if there is a way to get all timeouts together?

Comment: You cannot do that. The `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` functions return values, but you have to keep track of them with your own code.

Comment: How about using a static implementation of setTimeOut()?
THis can be called from all classes and also calls can be tracked.

Comment: You have to store return id somewhere in common array then you can check that

Comment: You may find the answers and packages mentioned here useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26057328/3412775

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not by default, no. You could make your own module that lets you keep track of the timers, and which gives you the list. ***Roughly***:

```
// ES2015+ version
const activeTimers = [];
exports.setTimeout = (callback, interval, ...timerArgs) => {
    const handle = setTimeout((...args) => {
        const index = activeTimers.indexOf(handle);
        if (index >= 0) {
            activeTimers.splice(index, 1);
        }
        callback(...args);
    }, interval, ...timerArgs);
    activeTimers.push(handle);
};
exports.getActiveTimers = () => {
    return activeTimers.slice();
};
```

...then use its `setTimeout` instead of the global one.

Answer (score 2):

There's no API to get registered timeouts, but there's a "way" to achieve your goal.

Create a new function, let's call it `registerTimeout`. Make sure it has the same signature as `setTimeout`. In this function, keep track of what you need (returned timer id, callback function, timeout period...) *and* register using `setTimeout`.

Now you can query your own data structure for registered timeouts.

Of course you should probably keep track of expired / triggered timeouts as well as cleared timeouts...