# Is it possibile to stop a script from another script?

Tags: javascript

I started to make a simple js debugger, and I was wondering if there is a way to stop an already running script if either it isn't responding or I want to stop it's `setInterval()` loop where we don't know the id of the loop.

---

I've noticed in the Chrome DevTools that every document has it's own script collection under `document.scripts`, but I couldn't find anything like a list of intervals (eg:`window.intervals`) or any response if any function is running,so I can't really determine if a function needs to be killed.

---

This could be useful when you want a webpage scanner extension or a debugger thet can refresh the page when the script is frozen.

### Edit:

The list of intervals has already been asked and solved in [How can I get all timers in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014061/how-can-i-get-all-timers-in-javascript) question.

Now the only question remains is: How can I determine if a script is frozen so it or the page can be killed?

Comment: Intervals and timers are set on the `window` object, not scoped to individual scripts.

Comment: Oh, you're right! But still there is no list that keeps track of them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get all timers in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46014061/how-can-i-get-all-timers-in-javascript)

Comment: I corrected the question, thanks!

Comment: If it's totally frozen then I believe there is nothing you can do from JS. JS is single-threaded so infinite loop will freeze it all, no way to kill it from other JS on a web page. On the other side if you make a plugin then there is a debugger API with sendCommand method that might be useful.

Comment: So there is no way to shut a script down. Thanks