# node does not terminate when script is done (event queue non empty?)

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, exec

In a **myscript.js** file I have:

```
import * as child from "child_process";

async function getCall() {
  const endpoint = 'some-endpoint'
  const response = await fetch(endpoint, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  })

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    console.error(msg);
    throw new Error(msg);
  }
  const json = await response.json()
  return json
}

await getCall()
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const execSync = child.execSync;
  var cmd = 'some-command'
  var stdout = execSync(cmd, { encoding: "utf-8" });
  console.log(stdout)
  
  var cmd = 'some-command'
  stdout = execSync(cmd, { encoding: "utf-8" });
  console.log(stdout)

}

console.log('done')
console.log(process._getActiveRequests())
//console.log(process._getActiveHandles())
console.log(process._getActiveHandles().length)

//process.exit()
```

When I run that with node myscript.js I get:

```
$ node myscript.js
done
[]
3
```

All is executed as expected, no error etc. but my local terminal just hangs.

From what I understand that means the node event queue is not empty (e.g from above it has 3 active handles):

[Node.js: inspect what's left in the event loop that's preventing the script from exiting naturally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057328/node-js-inspect-whats-left-in-the-event-loop-thats-preventing-the-script-from)

I can of course call:

`process.exit()`

at the end but I would like to understand whats causing it to hang.

If I remove the call to:

`await getCall()`

It works/script terminates as expected. So I suspect its related to `fetch` combined with the `child.execSync` calls.

I have also looked at top level awaits:

[How can I use async/await at the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level)

but not sure its related.

I expect the terminal to return for user input/that the script terminates successfully.

Comment: stdin,stdout,stderr are 3 opened files for you app to use. I've tried one liner, got notting, but with one console.log I got TTY writestream. Can you move 
 ``` const execSync = child.execSync;``` out of for loop?

Comment: I also tried that but it has not effect - it still hangs

Comment: wrap everything in function, than call this function. and also change every var to let.

Comment: Tried that as well, same result