# How to start debugger in nodeJS without command line?

Tags: node.js, debugging

In general we start a node process in debug mode like this

```
node --debug=5858 server.js
```

How to start debug mode in a already started node process using code or sending SIGUSR1 signal to node process.

I want to start debug mode without using any command line.

> This question is totally different than "already asked question". Its very shameful thing that people are tagging this question as already asked without understanding the question standard way.

Comment: What platform are you running Node.js on?

Comment: @Brad I am using mac os. but i don't think its depend on platform!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052548/node-js-how-to-attach-to-a-running-process-and-to-debug-the-server-with-a-conso

Comment: @ReverseCold I don't know why you tagged my question as your one! There is huge difference between both.

Comment: "How to start debug mode in a already started node process using code"

To me that looks the same. You can use tmux or just open another shell to get a command line.

If you tell us why you don't want to use the command line then maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: @ReverseCold What if i want to run debug on different port than 5858? What if i want to run multiple node process with debug in different different port? I clearly said that i don't wanna use command line. I want to signal the process. What if 'kill' not working ? I want a standard solution, not just trick.