# How do I use the `node inspect` debugger on an application that uses standard input?

Tags: node.js, javascript-debugger, node-inspector

I'm trying to track down the source of an error in a Node application that doesn't come with a stack trace.

The `node inspect` debugger supports a `breakOnException` command that I think will help me.

But my application needs to take input from standard input before it produces the error I am looking for, and `node inspect` seems to leave my standard input going to a persistent `debug>` prompt even afrer I `continue`, when the application being debugged is running and not paused. This is unlike `gdb`, where when you `continue` the debugger prompt goes away and you need to pause the application with Ctrl+C to get it back.

**How do I make `node inspect`'s prompt go away so I can type input into the application being debugged?** Alternately, if I run the application under `node --inspect` for remote debugging, **how can I connect to a remote debugging session on the command line?**

I know that a *browser* or an IDE like VSCode can connect to a remote NodeJS inspection session, but I can't seem to find a way to connect with the command-line debugger that is built in to `node`.

Answer (score 1):

`node inspect --help` doesn't document this at all, but if you launch one Node process with `node --inspect`, you can attach the built-in CLI debugger using the secret `-p <PID>` option. [Someone on Medium figured this out](https://scribe.rip/the-node-js-collection/live-debugging-node-js-apps-at-the-command-line-cd5b58f883e1), and did not give a source. It's also mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48214059) about debugging servers.

So, start your app:

```
$ node --inspect whatever.js arg arg arg
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/47219dfa-1b9b-40f8-92a9-0fc670bb2e0b
...
```

Then work out its PID:

```
$ pgrep -f "node --inspect"
12345
```

And then attach:

```
$ node inspect -p 12345
connecting to 127.0.0.1:9229 ... ok
debug>
```